# Missing cache statistics for cachedmethod decorator in cachetools

Tags: python, cachetools

I am implementing a cached method with cachetools like this:

```py
class CachedNum(object):

    def __init__(self, cachesize):
        self.cache = LRUCache(maxsize=cachesize)

    @cachedmethod(lambda self: self.cache)
    def get(self, num):
       return num + 1000

nums = CachedNum(cachesize=10)

nums.get.cache_info() # This is missing
nums.cache.cache_info() # The cache itself also has no statistics
```

In contrast there are no cache statistics about hits/misses. Is this an oversight in cachetools or do I need to track them myself?

Comment: This is not a Python issue *per se*. It's related to the non-standard *cachetools* module. Have you considered contacting the author? His details are on [this page](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/)